# All downloaded files treated as text files until Pantheon-Files restarted

Tags: pantheon-files

As the title suggests, any file I download - i.e. an .mp4, or .jpg shows up in Pantheon-Files as a text file.
Double click attempts to open said file in Code.
Right clicking shows "Open in Code" at the top.
The "Open with" menu item provides other installed text editors.
The work-around is to close Pantheon-Files and reopen it.